# R delete columns from data frame matching regex pattern

Tags: r, regex

I am running a script that generates data frames automatically.  In certain cases I get columns with a specific pattern such as `d123` or `d3452`.  It is basically the character d followed by few digits.  The number of digits could be just one or sometimes it goes up to a length of 4 characters.  I want to delete all the columns that match this particular pattern.  The example data frame is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(d1234=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5),c=c(4,5,3), d3245=c(3,2,4))
```

The df looks like this:

```
  d1234 b c d3245
1     1 3 4     3
2     2 4 5     2
3     3 5 3     4
```

From this I want to delete only the first and the last column that matches the pattern.  I have tried the following:

```
df <- data.frame(d1234=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5),c=c(4,5,3), d3245=c(3,2,4))
  colpat <- "[d[:digit:]]"
  if (colpat %in% names(df)) {
    d <- df[,!names(df) == colpat]  
  } else {
    d <- df
  }
  print(d)
```

But still the columns remain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grep` for regex matching of a pattern in the column name.  Here, the pattern is to check for letter 'd' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string, use the `invert = TRUE` (by default it is FALSE), and subset the columns with the numeric index

```
df[grep("^d\\d+$", names(df), invert = TRUE)]
#  b c
#1 3 4
#2 4 5
#3 5 3
```

Comment: Super...it works...and thanks for the explanation too

Comment: @Apricot.  Lets say if you get `grep("^d\\d+$", names(df))` 1 and 4 output, then `invert = TRUE`, does similar to setdiff on the sequence of columns and `setdiff(seq_along(df), c(1, 4))`

Answer (score 4):

For a tidyverse solution, you could use regex in the `matches` helper when selecting columns.

```
df %>%
  select(-matches("d\\d+$"))

  b c
1 3 4
2 4 5
3 5 3
```